# AForge.Video.FFMPEG XamlParseException

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg, aforge

I'm trying to set up a simple C# application where I want to record multiple USB webcams and save their feeds to some files. I'm using AForge.NET since this seems to be the most popular option for this sort of application. I can record video fine using the AForge.Video.VFW AVIWriter but due to a number of reasons I need to use the AForge.Video.FFMPEG VideoFileWriter. Whenever I try to use this class however, I get a System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException with no additional information or inner exceptions apart from a little additional information which is quite useless.

[image]

I have a simple code example to trigger the exception:

```
using AForge.Video.FFMPEG;

namespace CameraPrototype {
    public partial class MainWindow {
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();

            VideoFileWriter videoFileWriter = new VideoFileWriter();
        }
    }
}
```

I've also googled a bit around and tried some suggestion mentioned elsewhere:

- Checking all the boxes in Exceptions Settings, enabling breaks on all types of exceptions. I had hoped this would give me some more info when the exception was thrown, unfortunately it doesn't change anything.
- Copying the FFMPEG DLLs (swscale-2.dll, postproc-52.dll, etc) into the same folder as the application's built executable (../bin/Debug/). I 'm pretty sure the exception has something to do with ffmpeg, but this particular solution isn't working. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong here or I'm missing something for ffmpeg to work?

If anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong or how I can get more information about the exception, I would really appreciate any help. Let me know if I need to post any other information. Thanks!

**Edit:**
Though it doesn't really answer the question, I'm also open to suggestions for alternatives to AForge.NET, as long as it lets me record and save video from multiple USB webcams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give Accord.NET a try, it has ffmpeg bundled with the Accord.Video.FFMPEG, no extra setup needed. It provides the same features and functions as AForge.NET plus a little extra, but unless you need extended machine learning functionality, there isn't really a difference.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I wonder what I did differently, I tried copying the .dll's to the output and the output folder is the same for both my AForge.NET project and my Accord.NET project. I know this isn't exactly the answer to my question, but since it has solved my issues, I'll accept it anyway.